# If $Z(f)$ is the zero set, prove that $Z(f)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

**Introduction:**

Exercise from Principles of Mathematical Analysis, third edition (Rudin), page 98.

---

**Exercise:**

Let $f$ be a continous real function on a metric space $X$. Let $Z(f)$ (the zero set of $f$) be the set of all $p\in X$ at which $f(p)=0$. Prove that  $Z(f)$ is closed.

---

I think it's pretty hard to prove theorems, how do you usually begin? I do it by listing the definitions. Starting with listing the definition where my argument start and also the definition of my "goal".
$\text{ }$

### $\text{ }$

**Definition:**

*Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces. $E\subset X$, $p\in E$, and $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$. Then $f$ is said to be **continous** at $p$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that*

$$d_Y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon$$

for all points $x\in E$ for which $d_X(x,p)<\delta$.

**Definition:**

Let $X$ be a metric space, $E\subset X$ and $p\in X$. Then

$E$ is **closed** if every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$.

A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $p\neq q$ such that $q\in E$

A neighborhood of a point $p$ is a set $N_r(p)$ consisting of all points such that $d(p,q)<r$.

### $\text{}$

---

**Idea 1:**

Everytime, I do think "how hard can it be if I just list the definitions", but still, I don't manage to prove the theorem. First, I think if I should try to construct a proof by contradiction or not. That is, assume $Z(f)$ is not closed and hence there exists at least one limit point which isn't in $Z(f)$ and from there conclude a contradiction somehow. But then I don't know where to go from there so I change my mind to

**Idea 2:**

Just take it from the definition and since I know $Z(f)$ is the set of all points $p$ which satisfies $f(p)=0$, then I have something like $d_Y(f(x),0)<\epsilon$ (just taken from the definition), and do a proof by $\epsilon-\delta$. I have also though of this theorem:

A mapping $f$ of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$.

It says in the book that "This is a very useful characterization of continuity". But I don't really understand that theorem so I don't know how to use it either.

**Idea 3:**

Show that $Z(f)^c$ must be open. That is I have to show that every point of $Z(f)^c$ is an interior point of $Z(f)^c$. Which I don't know how to do...

There are so many theorems and definitions... so I don't know which is the right way to go or how to track it. How do you do when you want to prove something? Can you give me some tips or hints on where I should start? Thanks :)

Comment: Fact 1: A function is continuous if and only if the counterimage of any open set in the codomain (range) is an open set in its domain.

Comment: Isn't it enough to say that the preimage of a closed set for a continous function is closed?

Comment: If you know that preimages of open sets are open, then $f^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus \{0\})$ is open. It remain to show that the complement ($f^{-1}(0)$) of an open set is closed. But this may also be in your book, isn't it?

Comment: Fact 2: $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$ and $f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$

Comment: Fact 1 & Fact 2 imply @NicolòRuggeri's claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem in your book says that "if two points in $Y$ are to close, then their preimages are to close" (remember: closeness is measurable by mean of open sets in general topology).

It has a good corollary: $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed for every closed $V$.

Now, i'll suppose you are working with the usual topology. In your case, note that $Z(f)=f^{-1}(\{0\})$. But $\{0\}$ is closed in the usual topology. Since $f$ is continous, then $Z(f)$ is closed.

Comment: Ah thanks, now I think I get what the theorem says also :), It's usual so simple argument but still I don't manage to see them. Every closed $V$ in this case is the only set $\{0\}$ I guess then? :)

Comment: No. Every closed set is EVERY closed set. Since your $f$ is continuos, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed FOR ALL closed set. In particular, since $\{0\}$ is a closed set, then $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence in $Z(f)$ such that $x_n\to x\in X.$ We want to show $x \in Z(f).$ By continuity, $f(x_n) \to f(x).$ But $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n,$ so …