Rudin Ch 4 exercise 3: the zero set of a continuous function is closed
Let $f$ be a continuous real function on a metric space $X$. Let $Z(f)$ (the zero set of $f$) be the set of all $p \in X$ at which $f(p) = 0$. Prove that $Z(f)$ is closed.
My attempt
Let $p$ be a limit point of $Z(f)$. Then, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $d_x(x,p) < \delta$ for $x \in Z(f)$.
Since $f$ is continuous that implies that $d_y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon$, then $d_y(0,f(p)) < \epsilon$. So $d_y(0,f(p) = 0$ since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary. Hence $f(p) = 0$ so $p \in Z(f)$.
Is my proof sound?

No it is not: first, in "for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $d_x(x,p) < \delta$ for $x \in Z(f)$", the condition on your $\delta$ does not depend on $\epsilon$, and your $d_x$ makes no sense. Only $d$ does. Second, "Since $f$ is continuous that [i.e. $d_x(x,p) < \delta$] implies that $d_y(f(x),f(p))<\epsilon$" is false. Please review the precise epsilon-delta definition of continuity (with quantifiers in the correct order). And again, $d_y$ makes no sense.

There are already several posts about this exercise of Rudin. For instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577315

What do you mean by "only d does"?

I mean that $d$ has a meaning (it is the distance on your metric space), whereas your $d_x$ and $d_y$ are not defined. But the worse in your attempt is not that. It is the absence of logic in your manipulation of epsilon-deltas.

Instead of "for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $d_x(x,p) < \delta$ for $x \in Z(f)$", write (since $f$ is continuous at $p$) for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ s.t. forall $x\in X$ s.t. $d(x,p) < \delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$. Then, since $p$ is a limit point, there is (for such a $\delta$) at least one $x\in Z(f)$ s.t. $d(x,p) < \delta$. You can then conclude (for such an $x$) $|f(p)|<\epsilon$, so finally, indeed, "$f(p)=0$ since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary".

Ok I understood thanks for the help

Although it is an ability one should develop, I advocate a lot against using epsilons and deltas.
For this specific problem, sequences work much better. And if you want to use an "epsilon-delta like" argumentation, you can use neighbourhoods.
Epsilon-delta
When you talk about "closure" (being close), you do not need an epsilon and one delta. If the point $p$ is in $Z(f)$'s closure, then you can get a point $x \in Z(f)$ as close to $p$ as you wish. That is, for any $\delta > 0$, you can pick up an $x \in Z(f)$ that is $\delta$-close to $p$. In other words, $d(x, p) < \delta$.
Now, what you want is to conclude that $f(p) = 0$. The idea, here, is that the only real number that is arbitrarily close to $0$ is only the $0$ itself.
You are going to use continuity (at $p$). That means that you can manage to get $f(x)$ as close to $f(p)$ as you wish (we say arbitrarily close) by simply controlling how close $x$ is to $p$. In precise terms, given any $\varepsilon > 0$ (how close to $f(p)$), you can pick up a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x$ is $\delta$-close to $p$, you are assured that $f(x)$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $f(p)$.
Putting it all together, you can get an $x \in Z(f)$ such that $f(p)$ is as close as you wish ($\varepsilon$) to $f(x) = 0$. That is, $f(p)$ is arbitrarily close to $0$ and it is, therefore, equal to $0$.
Using sequences
If $p$ is a limit point in $Z(f)$, then there is a sequence $x_n \in Z(f)$ such that $x_n \rightarrow p$. Now, continuity implies that
$$f(p) = \lim f(x_n) = \lim 0 = 0.$$

@hff1: Yes. Very worth mentioning. :-)

This post and your answer are multiduplicates. See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4577471 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1639345. Well, the post itself was not really a duplicate since it was asking for the verification of a (multiflawed) proof,  not for alternative (correct) ones. But about the fake proof, comments are enough, imo. As for correct proofs, there are plenty on this site.

@AnneBauval: I agree. But you answered in your comments, I answered as an answer. I do not really know how SE will evolve to cope with this kind of phenomenon. I tried to: 1. correct and explain the OP's own arguments. 2. provide an alternative point of view. I do not really see a problem with "duplicates" after they are answered. Cross references, like yours, are very nice, though.
